# Specific classes not compiled with maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have to convert an old massive project from Ant to Maven. The project consists in various sub-projects (web applications) but the source code of all these projects are under various `src` folders. In order to create the war files we have a `dist target` for each module which selects and compiles specific classes, copy some files and create war.

I need to achieve the same result with Maven. **I cannot separate the project's code base in separate maven projects** so I have to come up with a solution. For now, it consists in a parent `pom` which have various modules (one for each sub-project). Here is an example of the project structure:

```
OldMassiveProject
     │   ├── src
     │   │    └── bunch.of.packages
     │   ├── other_src
     │   │    └── bunch.of.packages
     │   ├──  various_resources_folder
     ...
     │   ├── maven_modules
     │   │    ├── module_1
     │   │    │      └── pom.xml
     │   │    ├── module_2
     │   │    │      └── pom.xml
     ...
     │   │    ├── module_n
     │   │    │      └── pom.xml
     │   ├── deploy_configuration
     │   │    ├── module_1
     │   │    │      ├── spring_files
     │   │    │      └── web.xml
     │   │    ├── module_2
     │   │    │      ├── spring_files
     │   │    │      └── web.xml
     ...
     │   │    ├── module_n
     │   │    │      ├── spring_files
     │   │    │      └── web.xml
     │   └── pom.xml (parent pom)
```

My objective is to create a war for each module, I need to compile specific classes, but I don't have any successful result. This is what I've tried so far (module_1 pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-id</artifactId>
        <version>10.0</version>
        <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.base.folder>../../</project.base.folder>
        <project.base.src>${project.base.folder}src</project.base.src>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.base.src}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering> (not sure about this, I need to understand it better)
                <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/java</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/java/package1/ToCompile.java</include>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/java/package2/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>${project.base.folder}deploy_configuration/module_1/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warName>Module1</warName>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.base.src}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.sql</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean install` no `.class` files are generated, as a matter of fact the output for the compiler plugin is `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm relatively new to Maven.

## Edit

I corrected the `<include>` as pointed out in the comments by @eduyayo. I also corrected the source directory the resulting  `pom` is the following (only the compiler plugin part):

```
<build>
       <sourceDirectory>${project.base.src}</sourceDirectory>
       <directory>target</directory>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
                   <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                       <arg>-proc:none</arg>
                   </compilerArgs>
                   <includes>
                       <include>package1/ToCompile.java</include>
                       <include>package2/*.java</include>
                   </includes>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           ...
```

Now it seems that the compiler is able to find the specified classes but these are marked as duplicate by the compiler:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project module-1: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Development/Workspaces/OLDPROJ/OldMassiveProject/src/package2/Aclass.java:[25,8] duplicate class: package2.Aclass.java
[ERROR] /C:/Development/Workspaces/OLDPROJ/OldMassiveProject/src/package2/Cclass.java:[25,8] duplicate class: package2.Cclass.java
[ERROR] /C:/Development/Workspaces/OLDPROJ/OldMassiveProject/package1/ToCompile.java duplicate class: package1.ToCompile.java
```

But I'm pretty sure that class names are unique, so I can't understand why this error is raised.

### More info

I've tried to select only a dummy class, I can see that during compile 2 source file are compiled, that's strange:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ module-1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Development\Workspaces\OLDPROJ\OldMassiveProject\maven_modules\module_1\target\classes
```

Is this a normal behaviour? Maybe that's the error. Here's (part of) the log of the compiler:

```
[parsing started RegularFileObject[C:\Development\Workspaces\OLDPROJ\OldMassiveProject\src\testmaven\TestMaven.java]]
[parsing completed 17ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[C:\Development\Workspaces\OLDPROJ\OldMassiveProject\maven_modules\module_1\..\..\src\testmaven\TestMaven.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
```

In debug mode here's the configuration for `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [C:\Development\Workspaces\OLDPROJ\OldMassiveProject\maven_modules\module_1\..\..\src, C:\Development\Workspaces\OLDPROJ\OldMassiveProject\src]
```

That's odd it take's 2 times the `src` folder as `compileSourceRoots`.
Maybe this can explain something.

## Edit 2 (Workaround - possible solution)

Using `build-helper-maven-plugin` i can successfully compile the classes pointed in the  `<include>` of the `maven-compiler-plugin`. In my case I have deleted `<sourceDirectory>` in `<build>` ad added the `src` folder in `build-helper-maven-plugin`. It seems to work but the compiler picks up also the `src/main/java` folder which doesn't exist (no error is raised but it would be useful if I can remove this default setting). Here's the plugins part of the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src</source>
                        <source>other_src</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <includes>
                <include>package1/ToCompile.java</include>
                <include>package2/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: it is hard to follow your structure for me... one issue I see is that the `<include>` should be filtering package folders so you should remove the `${basedir}`. To add more source folders different than those in src, use the build-helper-maven-plugin

Comment: Why can't you use source as the base directory , when all the classes have same parent

Comment: If I understand you question: source is the base directory, in addition for other modules I need multiple src so I'll use the build-helper-maven-plugin. Otherwise, can you elaborate please?

Comment: did you run `mvn clean compile`?... the important part is to have run the clean target after you changed the src configuration so there won't be previous sh*t around when compiling...

Comment: Yeah I did, the error is the same no matter which classes I try to compile.

Comment: you're using `<directory>${project.base.src}</directory>` as a resource folder and as a source folder... it may have something to do

Comment: I removed the ```<webResources>``` in the ```maven-war-plugin``` so no more ```<directory>${project.base.src}</directory>```, nothing change. I've updated the question with more log of the compiler plugin.

Comment: it is still a `<resource>`, see??

Comment: The resource is a sub folder of src so I think that's not a problem. Anyway I may have found a workaround, dunno if it is a valid solution though. I appreciate your help btw.